# How to pass cookie/storage details from other website to the salesforce

Tags: apex, cookies, platform-cache

I am trying to pass some details from a non-salesforce website to salesforce website while creating the case.

Use Case : I am in a product website and if I have any question then I will click the help button and will be redirected the Salesforce page and if I want I can create a Case (in Salesforce platform). The challenge I am facing here I want few product information which is there in the product page.

Solution I have been thinking is use the Browser storage data but I am not sure if I will retain the same data when I have redirected to the salesforce page.

Is there any better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly send cookies, web storage, etc from one server to another. There's security restrictions in place that prevent this. You'll need to put this into the URL somehow, either as a query string (`/somepage?k1=v1&k2=v2`) or a url hash (`#someinfo`). The former can be read by the server (e.g. a Visualforce page's Apex controller), while the latter can be read by JavaScript client (e.g. Visualforce, LWC, or Aura scripts).